# How to resolve dyld and localtime leaks when profiling a project?

Tags: c, macos, valgrind, xcode-instruments, dyld

I am profiling my source. I see some allocations that are still alive at exit when I run `valgrind`.
Here is the summary:

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --show-reachable=yes --leak-check=full $BINARY

...

==20235== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20235==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20235==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20235==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20235==    still reachable: 20,228 bytes in 37 blocks
==20235==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20235==
```

The responsible libraries are:

`dyld`: all 81 mallocs have common calls as: (no clue)

[image: dyld]

`{libsystem_c, libsystem_notify, libdispatch}.dylib`: all 10 mallocs have common calls as:

[image: localtime]

`localtime(...)` defined in `time.h` uses `tzset(...)` to initialize and return me 
   a `struct tm*` which I shouldn't `free` myself because I did not allocate it.

How do I recover these 20,228 bytes which are still reachable?

### UPDATE

---

I am running Mac OS X

Comment: Are you sure you should care about that small leak? And what is your operating system? (If it is Linux or some recent Posix system, you might use `dlopen` etc... instead of `dyld`; if it is MacOSX I would not care about leaks inside `dyld` unless you really dynamically load many thousands of libraries)

Comment: running Mac OS X, updated the question.

Comment: I would not care about these leaks... They are apparently not your fault... Why do you want to recover these 20kbytes; the MacOSX kernel will (like any Unix-like kernel) recover that memory when the process exits (either normally thru the `_exit` syscall or equivalent, or thru a terminating signal eg `SIGSEGV` or `SIGABRT`)

Comment: @Basile - *"I would not care about these leaks..."* - If a tool like Valgrind is a security gate, then you have to care about them.

Comment: But AFAIU this is some bug from MacOSX...

Comment: Also see [Add localtime() to internal ignore list for OS X](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/34510058/) on the Valgrind Developer's mailing list.