# Does memory for localtime need to be deallocated?

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
void log(){
    time_t current = time(0);
    tm *ptm = localtime(&current);
        stuf...
}
```

Just want to be sure - do i need to release tm pointer allocated memory at the end of the method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the result struct of localtime allocated in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694365/how-is-the-result-struct-of-localtime-allocated-in-c)

Comment: Also see [How to resolve dyld and localtime leaks when profiling a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10105181)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No you should not deallocate it,the structure is statically allocated.

Check the **[documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)**:

> **Return value**
>   **pointer to a static internal `std::tm` object** on success, or `NULL` otherwise. The structure may be shared between `std::gmtime`, `std::localtime`, and `std::ctime`, and may be overwritten on each invocation.

Comment: what do you mean by statically allocated? dosnt it allocated on the heap by the localtime implementation?

Comment: @user1495181: Added reference for you.

Comment: OH thanks , i missed it, and now i know that localtime is not thread safe.:(

Comment: @user1495181: Posix has `localtime_r`, which is thread-safe. You pass in a pointer to the `struct tm` result. But it's not in standard C++. It *is* in the latest version of C (C11), as `localtime_s`.

Comment: @user1495181 It **could** be thread safe. E.g. in MSVC++ this structure is maintained per each thread. Check your compiler docs.

Answer (score 8):

No, you shouldn't. This structure is statically allocated and shared by the functions `gmtime` and `localtime`. Each time either one of these functions is called the content of this structure is overwritten.

So be careful with results - e.g. copy them immediately and don't store the pointer.